# A C++ equivalent for Encoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(str)?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

This function calculates the number of bytes of the string "str" when encoded in UTF-16.

My question is, what would be a C++ equivalent to implement this?

Comment: @M.Babcock g++ compilable, can use C++0x features (if there is one)

Comment: Have you considered using Mono for your cross platform requirements?

Comment: @M.Babcock I think Mono would require the whole package to be written in C# and then using something like "mono " to execute the file? Is there a .net-like library to support this?

Comment: "Execute the file"? A library to support what?

Comment: @M.Babcock For example, is there a C++ library on Linux that could somehow act the role of a .net framework?

Comment: @M.Babcock Based on my own understanding of Mono, I think it does not support C++? Is there a tutorial on how to link Mono with C++?

Comment: Yep, the Mono website is full of libmono integration examples: http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

Comment: What is your storage encoding? e.g. You read from a source which is encoded UTF-8?

Comment: @derekhh - Any luck hosting Mono in your application to help mitigate your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just standard C++

Standard C++, including C++11, is not Unicode aware. To get the kind of measuring function you're talking about, you'll have to use another support library like ICU or Windows API functions or iconv or somesuch.

Comment: @OsmanTuran: That's a long way away from being unicode aware, or doing what the OP asked.